# Gravity: Why Do things fall to Earth?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity, spacetime, curvature

If gravity is in reality spacetime geometry why when I drop an object on the surface of the Earth does it fall to the ground? Does spacetime push it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What is exactly your thinking behind "gravity is space-time geometry"?*

In layman's terms, general relativity tells us that a particle with some defined mass will curve space-time, causing a gravitational attraction to be *felt* by the objects around it. When you drop an object on the surface of the Earth, the curvature of space-time caused by the large mass of the Earth, relative to the small mass of the object, causes it to be attracted by gravity and fall to the ground.

[image]
<sub>(source: [space.com](http://i.space.com/images/i/000/046/083/original/gravity-probe-b.jpg?1425570731))</sub>

Comment: In your graphic there is a spacecraft presumably in orbit - presumably following a geodesic path - it has velocity relative to the Earth - If it had no  velocity  why would it travel to the earth? Does spacetime push it?

Comment: @PaulStanley As you pass through time, the distortion of space-time accelerates the satellite towards the centre of the Earth. If the satellite had no velocity, it would accelerate towards the Earth. It is not sensible to say that space-time *pushes* the satellite since it is just an abstract mathematical model. For further notice, I think you should read through the similar questions above, since this question is a duplicate.